# Stack Overflow/Exception when trying to build a recursive only "ruler" (no loops!)

Tags: c++, exception, recursion

I had to design a ruler using only recursion (no loops).  The user puts in the ruler length and the depth(height) of the tick marks.  I managed to build this just fine using simple for and while loops, but when I tried to translate it into recursion, I am having some trouble.  I get a stack overflow and first chance exception at the end of running the file, BUT, just before the error kills it, I get the correct output.  I've been using the test cases length: 4 and depth: 5, and length: 12 and depth: 3.

If anyone has an idea of how much I screwed up my recursive effort, I'm all ears.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void solve (int, int, int, string, int);

int main()
{
    int depth, length;
    cout << "Enter a ruler length: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << endl << "Enter a marking depth: ";
    cin >> depth;

    int i = 0;
    string ruler = "";
    int size = length * pow(2, (depth-1));

    solve(length, depth, i, ruler, size);


    int x;
    cin >> x;

    return 0;
}

void solve (int length, int depth, int i, string ruler, int size)
{
    if (depth > 0)
    {

        int inc = pow(2, depth-1);

        if (i <= (size))
        {   
            if (i % inc == 0) {
                cout << "|";
            }

            if (i % inc != 0) {
                cout << " ";                
            }

            solve (length, depth, ++i, ruler, size);


        }
        cout << "\n";

    }

    solve (length, depth-1, 0, ruler, size);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a return point from `solve` recursion function, like:

```
void solve (int length, int depth, int i, string ruler, int size)
{

    if (depth > 0)
    {
        int inc = pow(2, depth-1);

        if (i <= (size))
        {   
            if (i % inc == 0) {
                cout << "|";
            }

            if (i % inc != 0) {
                cout << " ";                
            }

            solve (length, depth, ++i, ruler, size);
        }
        cout << "\n";            
    }
    else
    {
         return; //<<<---- return out  
    }

    solve (length, depth-1, 0, ruler, size);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It stops the recursive job early and it only produces the output for the "first depth", resulting in only the top line of the ruler.

Comment: @TheRationalist you want to return when 'depth == 0`?

Comment: Yes. And I have tried doing an if statement to return when depth == 0.  When I do that, though, I lose the exception error, but get a bunch of extra, unwanted output.  I'll get the desired result at first, then followed by lines and lines of strange results.  The best example is trying length and depth with value 2.  You can see the leftover output.

Comment: at least return out from recursion function will stop crashing, you need to fix your code logic next.

Comment: Alright. Well, thanks for your help.